# Регулярное выражение на php, как вырезать ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть код, который надо вырезать весь, с помощью регулярок.
Раньше он был таблицей и я делал так:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<pre>
<?
    $s=file_get_contents('http://www.komsomolec58.ru/afisha-kino.html');

    //print_r($s);

    preg_match("/<tbody>(.+)<\/tbody>/Ums",$s,$m);

    $table=$m[1];
    print_r($m); 
?>
</pre>
<?echo $table;?>
</table>
```

Но сейчас это стало на дивах и как бы я не бился на основе старого кода - никак не могу подредактировать его, прошу помощи.

```
<div class="art-postcontent">
<div class="art-article"><p><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">8 августа</span></strong><br><br><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">БОЛЬШОЙ ЗАЛ</span></strong><br>09:00 – Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>11:10 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика)16+<br>13:20 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>15:30 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>17:40 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>19:50 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>22:00 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br><br><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">МАЛЫЙ ЗАЛ</span></strong><br>09:00 -Турбо 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>11:00 - Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>13:10 - РЭД 2 (боевик/триллер) 12+<br>15:25 - Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>17:35 - Заклятие(ужасы/триллер) 16+<br>19:45 - РЭД 2 (боевик/триллер) 12+<br>22:00 - Росомаха:Бессмертный 3D(боевик/фантастика) 12+<br><br><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">9 - 14 августа</span></strong><br><br><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">БОЛЬШОЙ ЗАЛ</span></strong><br>09:00 – Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>11:10 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>13:20 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>15:30 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>17:40 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>19:50 – Элизиум: Рай не на Земле (боевик/фантастика) 16+<br>22:00 – Заклятие(ужасы/триллер) 16+<br><br><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">МАЛЫЙ ЗАЛ</span></strong><br>09:00 -Турбо 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>11:00 - Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>13:10 - РЭД 2 (боевик/триллер) 12+<br>15:25 - Смурфики-2 3D (мультфильм) 0+<br>17:35 - Мы — Миллеры (комедия) 16+<br>19:45 - РЭД 2 (боевик/триллер) 12+<br>22:00 - Росомаха:Бессмертный 3D(боевик/фантастика) 12+</p>

</div><span class="article_separator">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @oldzas, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: невозможно полноценно парсить HTML с помощью регулярных выражений.
используйте специально для этого предназначенные функции DOM

Comment: да мне бы хоть как нибудь, от сих до сих кусок вырвать и все

Comment: Какой див нужно вырезать7

Comment: Советую отпарсить HTML. Нет регулярок -- нет проблем :)

Comment: По-моему в регулярках нет проблем. Если их хорошо знать-то это превращается в мощный инструмент.

Comment: И вы хотите чтобы автор вопроса каждый раз, когда ему нужно будет вытянуть данные из HTML-страницы, задавал тут вопрос про регулярки? Здесь они просто не нужны, есть более простое и красивое решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/<div class=art-postcontent>(.+)</div><span class=article_separator>/', $html, $array);
```

Comment: А еще добавить ключи sU

Comment: Безусловно

Comment: Вы вообще проверяете свои выражения, прежде чем публиковать ответ? Это выражение не будет работать в принципе. И завершится с ошибкой `Unknown modifier 'd' ` Даже если исправить это - то все равно работать не будет, так как не соответствует строке.